# Ubuntu Software Updater randomly popping up

Tags: update-manager, software-updater

I don't know why but it randomly pops up sometimes every hour sometimes every 30 minutes with the message "The software is up to date"

Comment: I am also experiencing this and would like to know how to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

**This would help you**

- Open `Software Sources` by running following command in terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

  ```
  sudo software-properties-gtk
  ```
- Then go to <kbd>Updates</kbd> tab.
- Chose <kbd>Never</kbd> Under `Automatically Check for Updates` option.
- <kbd>Close</kbd> the window.
- Update your repository by:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update.
  ```

After that it should not pop-up any message. Repeat same step if you again want Ubuntu to pop-up for you. Just change <kbd>Never</kbd> to any other option. 
Try it once.. Reply if something goes wrong..

Comment: But this would stop checking for updates too!

Comment: @Jobin: Yes! you are absolutely correct. This will stop checking updates but also stop annoying popping update notifications. I've also mentioned the way to re-enable the update notification. Updating is not a daily task so some one can follow this way to prevent from the annoying message.